# Need to set up Android Chrome to work with Windows Authentication for intranet site

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, authentication

I am developing an intranet site in MVC and it is using Windows Authentication almost everything works.  One page was designed to be used on a phone.

On the iPhone (safari) it works just fine, the user is prompted for user name and password, and then the page is displayed.  However, on Android with the Chrome browser we only get

Https

> This webpage is not available
>   DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Http

> This webpage is not available
>   ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Since this site works on my computer with Chrome and even on an iPhone with Safari that it is likely a setting on my phone.  Any help would be appreciated.  If more information is needed to answer the question I'll try to provide it.

Comment: when you say windows authentification, it's .htpasswd or Windows technologies ? What are you website language ?

Comment: windows technologies, windows network in config file <authentication mode="Windows" />

Answer (score 0):

After talking with someone at my company who has done some android development, he suggested using the IP address of the web server instead of the DNS name.

It worked immediately without any other changes.